# NPX not found using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to use react to build a tic tac toe board, and I can't get React to create an app and launch on my computer so that I can upload my code to the server. The below picture is the error I get... does anyone have any advice?? Thank you in advance!
[image]

I tried to download the npm command, but that wouldn't work, so then I tried to uninstall it and that wouldn't work... I'm just trying to create a react app, please help!!

Comment: `sudo` isn't a windows command. I'd recommend trying documentation or a windows tutorial if you're following one - but removing `sudo` should install that package.

Comment: Do you have node installed? npm and npx come bundled with node, which is required for create-react-app.